# Add custom new lines with Gulp uglify and Concat

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using Gulp and gulp uglify and concat to create production JS. How can I add new lines before license comments?

Example output

```
/*! Version 1 */
function Test1(){}/*! Version 2 */
function Test(){}
```

Desired output

```
/*! Version 1 */
function Test1(){}
/*! Version 2 */
function Test(){}
```

My code that wraps the gulp sequence

```
function gulpDeploy(src, fileName, dest){
    gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(concat(fileName, {
            newLine:'\n;'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify({
            preserveComments : 'license'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

It looks like the newLine option should do it, but it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be very interested in seeing alternative answers that use just `uglify` and `concat` to do this, but a naive fix using `gulp-replace` would be this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
  gulp.src('file*.js')
    .pipe(concat('output.js', { newLine: '\n;' }))
    .pipe(uglify({ preserveComments: 'license' }))
    .pipe(replace(/(\/\*\! Version [^*]* \*\/)/g, '\n$1')) // Version-comments to new line
    .pipe(replace(/^\s*\r?\n/gm, '')) // Remove empty lines that may get left
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

I would've preferred to have the first regex find only Version-comments that don't already start on the start of a new line (so the second `replace` call wouldn't be needed), but it seemed quite hard to get that regex to work (for one because negative lookbehind doesn't seem to work, or I'd think you could use [`(?<!^)\/\*\! Version [^*]* \*\/` to do it...](https://regex101.com/r/pW5dR8/1))

Comment: Beautiful. A bit slow, but completely worth it.